# How are *kri uksivs* marked in a Megillah/klaf that has vowels?

Tags: safrus, trop-cantillation, haftarah, 5-megilloth

Chayei Adam brings down ([155:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam%2C_Shabbat_and_Festivals.155.14?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Chayei_Adam,_Vilna,_1844&lang=bi&with=Navigation&lang2=en)) that technically yes, one could take a handwritten Megillas Esther, add in the vowels and cantillation marks, and it would still be kosher:

> ואין לעשות בה נקודות או לכתוב בה הטעמים מ"מ בדיעבד כשר ואפי' לכתחלה מותר אם אין שם מי שיודע לקרות כהוגן או להקרות לש"ץ

I've heard that some shuls in Israel that want to use a handwritten parchment of the various books of the Prophets for weekly haftarahs use one with vowels and other marks added in, so the reader doesn't need to memorize those in advance.

I understand how you could take the basic text and add symbols, which are not-text. But how do you mark it to note that a word is pronounced differently? Or not pronounced at all, or pronounced despite being not appearing in writing? Can they add notes in the margins? Some other option? Or is there no way to do this?

Comment: Are you asking for halachicaly valid ways or for practical tips? Seemingly it doesn't matter halachicaly since the whole thing is assuming we don't mind you using an essentially pasul item (like a megillah missing some words)

Comment: @DoubleAA How is it passul?

Comment: @N.T. obviously, by having vowels / missing some words...

Comment: @DoubleAA not sure I follow. Chayei Adam says a megillas Esther with trop and nikud is kshera. (Or are you saying it's "kshera" like a megillah missing 49%, and thus only a din in megillas Esther?)

Comment: @Shalom That is just a word game of "kosher". You can use this item for the mitzva of reading esther on purim but it's hard to imagine it is a proper sefer (perhaps nafka mina for kavod). Call it what you want.

Comment: Btw not everyone agrees the rule that 49% missing is only for esther. Tosfot applies it even to Torahs, and we can debate which neviim is more similar to, but anyway if you are writing a Sefer Aftarta (which is the only context people nowadays ever write in nikkud) you must be resigned to the fact that words won't all be there.

Comment: @DoubleAA interesting, thank you!

Comment: In Orach Chaim 691:9 it says that even if the Berachos are written inside the Megillah, it is still Kosher

Comment: @DoubleAA So, basically Kosher.

Comment: @N.T. I don't know what you are saying